# mongodb atlas - rockmongo

Tags: php, mongodb, rockmongo

I am having huge issues connecting to atlas (mongodb) via rockmongo.

Here is the configuration I have.

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_options"] = array("replicaSet" => "LuxeMassage-shard-0");
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_name"] = "LuxeMassage Cluster";//mongo server name
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_host"] = "mongodb://luxemassage-shard-00-00-0kahc.mongodb.net:27017,luxemassage-shard-00-01-0kahc.mongodb.net:27017,luxemassage-shard-00-02-0kahc.mongodb.net:27017/admin?replicaSet=LuxeMassage-shard-0";//mongo host
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_port"] = "27017";//mongo port
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_timeout"] = 0;//mongo connection timeout
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_db"] = "MONGO_DATABASE";//default mongo db to connect, works only if mongo_auth=false
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_user"] = "MONGO_USERNAME";//mongo authentication user name, works only if mongo_auth=false
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_pass"] = "MONGO_PASSWORD";//mongo authentication password, works only if mongo_auth=false
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = true;//enable mongo authentication?

$MONGO["servers"][$i]["control_auth"] = false;//enable control users, works only if mongo_auth=false
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["control_users"]["admin"] = "admin";//one of control users ["USERNAME"]=PASSWORD, works only if mongo_auth=false

$MONGO["servers"][$i]["ui_only_dbs"] = "";//databases to display
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["ui_hide_dbs"] = "";//databases to hide
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["ui_hide_collections"] = "";//collections to hide
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["ui_hide_system_collections"] = false;//whether hide the system collections
```

I have allowed the IP address whitelisted, so I can connect via ssh terminal. So connection to atlas works but when I try mongodb atlas via rockmongoo it bruings the error

```
Unable to connect MongoDB, please check your configurations. MongoDB said:No candidate servers found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is lack of SSL support for the RockMongo client.  Another webclient is recommended with Atlas.

Comment: HOW do I do that, as mongodb has advised me to no longer use rockmongo as it does not support ssl

Comment: I see that they have not released an update.  It looks like this still is not possible.  I have corrected the above answer as well.